# How to send variable values to email/external file

Tags: file, variables, actionscript, external

I'm not an Expert in Flash... So, I want to do a Register Page, and get the variable values. I want to send variables to a external file or to my email.

I've got 2 Input Text Components with this Instance Names:

name
password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your application is running in the Flash player you'll need a server-side script to send data via email or to save it to a file on the server. There are loads of tutorials out there to help you out with this, but here are a couple I found which look useful:

1. [Contact form with ActionScript 3.0 and PHP](http://www.webdesignmo.com/blog/2008/08/14/flash-contact-form-in-actionscript-3/)
2. [Saving data to a text file with ActionScript 3.0 and PHP](http://www.seinia.com/tutorials/SavingAS3DataToATextFile/)